# $\sin n$ having a closed form expression with no complex terms?

Tags: trigonometry

[All angles are in degrees] I have heard that we cannot express $\sin 1$ in closed form with no complex terms. However, I know that we can derive $\sin 18$ by solving $\cos 3x = \sin 2x$. Thus we can get trig values for $72$ degrees and then get to $\sin 3$ as we know every term of the expansion of $\sin 75-72$. And so we can have sine of every integral multiple of $3$ in closed form with no complex terms.

But what about others such as $\sin 5$? Well if we know $\sin 1$, our problems would be solved, which I have heard is not closed form with no complex terms. Can anyone *prove* that? Maybe we can use some other method or some sort of geometric solution to find out, $\sin 1$ or $\sin n$ for any natural number but it turns out not. Why?

Comment: I think you might find your answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon).

Comment: @DavidMitra Is not there something more elementary?

Comment: Perhaps for specific angles; I'm not sure...

Comment: What is a "closed form with no complex terms"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well something like a real number with an expression having finite number of terms and does not contain the symbol $i$.

Comment: A [list of exact values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants#Table_of_constants) of trigonometric functions, for all multiples of $3^0$.

Comment: @Lucian: You might want to use "3^\circ". (I misread it as 3^0 = 1 at first.)